# Complex harmonic function , How to find the relationship between a,b, and c

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the relationship between the coefficients a, b, c
so that the function ax ^ 2 + bxy + cy ^ 2 is harmonic
I'm stuck looking for the relationship between a, b, c because I know a couple of things:
ux = 2ax + by
uxx = 2a
uy = bx + 2cy
uyy = 2c
  Therefore uxx + uyy = 0 and 2a + 2c = 0 it is guaranteed that the function is harmonic (ok, that what I understand but not sure)
(I'm sorry for my English)

Comment: So you want $a=-c$.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Then conclude that $a=-c$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}$, the set of reals.

Comment: My only doubt is that I can not find the relationship of b with others.

Comment: @Natasha you have showed $b$ can be anything, it doesn't matter what it is. As long as $a=-c$, it is harmonic.

Comment: Thank u! :) now totally  clear :)